# delete api not working because of dependecy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am creating REST Delete method to delete record from table, due to dependency I am not able to delete it, I searched and tried solution but no luck, here is the problem:

```
table A:
name, id, description, userid

table user have user details and userid

there is a relationship between A.userid and user.userid
```

I want to delete row from table A without delete row in user table as same user is assign to some other table B.
I am using Hibernate Mapping and JPA remove() method to delete it, with CascadeType.ALL and Mysql DB.
even we have more dependencies on table A.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but if table A have 3 entries which link with same user id and i want to delete only one entry, so I can not make user id value as null as it is also pointing to other 2 entries.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question well enough the first time, I see that table A is has the child records as relating to table user. What kind of error are you getting when trying to delete a record from table A, as it shouldn't violate any relationship between User and Table A, as Table A houses a foreign key to User

Comment: If I do oneToMany on B in class A, is it mandatory to define ManyToOne on A in class B ? or vice versa

Comment: Tables either have a one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many or no relationship at all. It is up to you to design your database correctly. Ask yourself can an item in A be related to many in table B and can an Item in B related to many in table A if so that is a many-to-many and you should create a junction table which houses the primary keys of both tables A and B as foreign keys combined into a primary key of your junction table, TABLE AB for example could be your junction table, if B can have many A's but A has only one B, you have a one-to-many relationship between B and A, and

Comment: A would house a foreign key of B's primary key to relate the multiple A items to the B item.

Comment: thank you Ryan but hibernate provided annotation OneToMany and ManyToOne both

Comment: ok, I don't use ORMs as I prefer doing the database design work myself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i will go with one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many and try to implement ORM mapping, concepts will be same :)